# Why does this script move my header down?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a spreadshirt shop integrated on my website but when I add their recommended javascript code it moves my header on the page down. It only happens on that page. My website is https://www.irelandsfuture.com/store and the script looks like this:

```
<div id="myshop">Spreadshop loading...</div>
        <script>
            var spread_shop_config = {
              prefix: 'https://shop.spreadshirt.ie',
              shopName: 'irelandsfuture',
              baseId: 'myshop',
            };
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://shop.spreadshirt.net/js/shopclient.nocache.js"></script>
```

Any ideas how to prevent this please?

Thanks

Comment: You have an SVG at the top of your page, it has an attribute `display='none'`, you maybe meant to do `style="display:none"` instead, or you maybe have some missing CSS that would target `display="none"` attribute.

Comment: It does not look like the problem page is at your home page. It is difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing the whole live page. Please update.

Comment: What makes you think this is the script that is causing the issue?

Comment: Okay I think I can see in the plugin where this gets added but it looks a mess. Any chance you can help decipher this please?:                                                                     . wp-core-ui input[type=checkbox]:checked::before { content: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27%20viewBox%3D%270%200%2020%2020%27%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%27M14.83%204.89l1.34.94-5.81%208.38H9.02L5.78%209.67l1.34-1.25%202.57%202.4z%27%20fill%3D%27%333%27%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");

Comment: @Sean Walton yeah home page is fine just the url in my initial post with store at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened the dev tools you have an SVG at the top of your page.

[image]

add display: none like this :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style=" display: none;">
```

instead of :

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" display="none">
```

Comment: Okay I think I can see in the plugin where this gets added but it looks a mess. Any chance you can help decipher this:.                                                                                               
 wp-core-ui input[type=checkbox]:checked::before {
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27%20viewBox%3D%270%200%2020%2020%27%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%27M14.83%204.89l1.34.94-5.81%208.38H9.02L5.78%209.67l1.34-1.25%202.57%202.4z%27%20fill%3D%27%333%27%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");

Comment: Full css can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_qf546KF0RCKRTJKJSpH9NE9VqnLIo8/view?usp=drivesdk